# tabhost in a relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Good morning,
Can I put a tabhost in a relativelayout without making mistakes?
I can not get it to work. Place the code and the image is what I want to get (a webview above tabhost and it must be under the buttons)

[image: This is what I want to get]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="-" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="+" />

      <TabHost 
        android:id="@+id/tabHost" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />





 <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
  android:id=  "@android:id/tabcontent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tabX1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500px"

        />

    </LinearLayout>  


    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tabX2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



    </LinearLayout>     




    </FrameLayout>
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"   
             android:layout_height ="wrap_content">
           </TabWidget>
</TabHost>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

   </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT

this is error:

"" does not set the required layout_width attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"
"" does not set the required layout_height attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"
"" does not set the required layout_width attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"
"" does not set the required layout_height attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"
TabHost requires a TabWidget with id "android:id/tabs".

You must supply a layout_width attribute.
You must supply a layout_height attribute.
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

Comment: You need the webview inside the tabHost?

Comment: I did so .... but when I run this I get an error:

Comment: Error? Okay. Post the error or Logcat trace.

Comment: use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` with tabhost

Comment: Are you telling about `TabWidget'`s alignment here?

Comment: the TabWidget must be placed under the webview...

Comment: yes TabWidget's alignment...................

Comment: Change your `TabHost'`s id as `@android:id/tabhost` Instead of `@+id/tabHost`

Comment: ok but I get the same error. while I try the easiest solutions using two relativelayout though I do not get the thing desired

Comment: Actually, what have you tried for? Showing the webview in both tabs or what? Explain it detailed by edit your question

Comment: the second tab should refer to a ListView that must occupy the same position as the webview, but I have a layout problem that I have not yet occupied.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12484/discussion-between-spk-and-antilope)